# Consumer offset reset needed after configuring retention.ms in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I deleted by data using retention.ms = 10000 and set it back to almost 7-10 days retention period.

In that case i only consumed almost 450 of the messages and about 20,000  where not consumed.

now i am getting

```
Current offset 439 for partition [test,0] out of range; reset offset to 22545
```

how to fix it, i donot want to do it programtically as my java consumer api's are written and they should not be changed in such cases.